# Optimize the number of accesses to a database when working with IQueryable<T> and custom functions

Tags: c#, repository, iqueryable

In my **C# Class Library project** I have a method that needs to compute some statistics `GetFaultRate`, that, given a `date`, computes the number of products with faults over the number of products produced.

```
float GetFaultRate(DateTime date)
{
    var products = GetProducts(date);
    var faultyProducts = GetFaultyProducts(date);

    var rate = (float) (faultyProducts.Count() / products.Count());

    return rate;
}
```

Both methods, `GetProducts` and `GetFaultyProducts` take the data from a **Repository** class `_productRepository`.

```
IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(DateTime date)
{
    var products = _productRepository.GetAll().ToList();

    var periodProducts = products.Where(p => CustomFunction(p.productionDate) == date);

    return periodProducts;
}

IEnumerable<Product> GetFaultyProducts(DateTime date)
{
    var products = _productRepository.GetAll().ToList();

    var periodFaultyProducts = products.Where(p => CustomFunction(p.ProductionDate) == date && p.Faulty == true);

    return periodFaultyProducts;
}
```

Where `GetAll` has signature:

```
IQueryable<Product> GetAll();
```

The products in the database are many and it takes a lot of time to retrieve them and convert `ToList()`. I need to enumerate the collection since any custom function such as `CustomFunction`, cannot be executed in a `IQueryable<T>`.

My application gets stuck for a long time before obtaining the fault rate. I guess it is because of the large number of objects to be retrieved. I can indeed remove the two functions `GetProducts` and `GetFaultyProducts` and implement the logic inside `GetFaultRate`. However since I have other functions that use `GetProducts` and `GetFaultyProducts`, with the latter solution I have only one access to the database but a lot of duplicate code.

What can be a good compromise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, don't convert the `IQueryable` to a list.  It forces the entire data set to be brought into memory all at once, rather than just calling `Where` directly on the query which will allow you to filter the data as it comes in.  This will *substantially* decrease your memory footprint, and (very) marginally increase the runtime speed.  If you need to convert an `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable` so that the `Where` isn't executed by the database simply use `AsEnumerable`.

Next, getting *all* of the data is something you should avoid if at all possible, especially multiple times.  You'd need to show us what your date function does, but it's possible that it is something that could be done on the database.  Any filtering you can do at all at the database will *substantially* increase performance.

Next, you really don't need two queries here.  The second query is just a subset of the first, so if you *know* that you'll always be using both queries then you should just just perform the first query, bring the results into memory (i.e. with a `ToList` that you store) and then use a `Where` on that to filter the results further.  This will avoid another database trip as well as all of the data processing/filtering.

If you won't always be using both queries, but will sometimes use just one or the other, then you can improve the second query by filtering out on `Faulty` before getting all items.  Add `Where(p => p.Faulty)` *before* you call `AsEnumerable` and filter on the date information *after* calling `AsEnumerable` (and that's if you can't convert any of the date filtering to filtering that can be done at the database).

It appears that in the end you only need to compute the ratio of items that are faulty as compared to the total.  That can easily be done with a single query, rather than two.

You've said that `Count` is running really slowly in your code, but that's not really true.  `Count` is simply the method that is actually enumerating your query, whereas all of the other methods were simply building the query, not executing it.  However, you can cut your performance costs drastically by combining the queries entirely.

```
var lookup = _productRepository.GetAll()
.AsEnumerable()//if at all possible, try to re-write the `Where` 
               //to be a valid SQL query so that you don't need this call here
.Where(p => CustomFunction(p.productionDate) == date)
.ToLookup(product => product.Faulty);

int totalCount = lookup[true].Count() + lookup[false].Count();
double rate = lookup[true].Count() / (double) totalCount;
```

Comment: "which will allow you to filter the data as it comes in" - doubt that in context of eg EF... data does not get filtered on the stream in the app (like it would be on an `IEnumerable<T>`) - it gets  filtered before the output is sent to app... and there comes "and (very) marginally increase the runtime speed." into play: I doubt that either - depending on the query it *might* be possible to achieve better performance if doing some groupings/queries and alikes in the .net-domain (if you have the appropriate datastructure for your query)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair `"doubt that in context of eg EF"` Well as that code would be after a call to `AsEnumerable` it wouldn't be in the context of EF, it would just be an IEnumerable.  As for the marginal performance, I was simply saying that using `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` will avoid creating populating, and then discarding a List.  Compared to database transactions that's pretty marginal, but it is *something*.  The primary problem with the `ToList` though is the memory it will consume, and also the fact that the `IEnumerable` processing can't start until all rows are fetched.

Comment: the main issues with `List<T>` are: (1) memory-footprint, because all items need to remain in memory, (2) performance-footprint, because `List<T>` is *intelligent* when it gets to its (index-)boundaries (it magically enlarges itself and creates some more empty indices). issue 1 is constant, whereas issue 2 occures n-times ... I am totally with you and your explanation, just felt that it needed some enhancements :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Yes, there is a performance cost with the List resizing itself, but even that resizing will have a larger memory footprint than performance footprint.  And again, there is a very large DB call going on here; that's going to completely obscure the processing involved with populating the list by comparison.  As the saying goes, "you can hide anything behind a DB call".

Comment: Thanks! I tried all your suggestions and I improved a bit the speed. I noticed that the operation that takes the longer time is the Count() (see edit). Is there any way for Count() to perform faster? Is it better to execute it in a IQueryable?

Comment: @CiccioMiami Well, it would be *substantially* better to execute the count as an `IQueryable`, but to do that the whole query needs to do that, which I've said several times you should do if at all possible.  You should be absolutely sure that your date function can't be refactored into something that the query provider can translate.  That said, `Count` isn't what's being slow, it's simply the function that's actually evaluating the query for the first time.  By not performing two queries, as I've shown in my edit, you can cut the time in half.

Comment: Thanks I tried your solution with ToLookup but stil the count takes ages. My CustomFunction converts a string to a valid DateTime. The string is stored in a database according to an awkward format(YYYYMMDDhhmm) and I am not authorized to change it. I guess the only solution is to convert the string into DateTime directly in the database

Comment: @CiccioMiami You should not see `Count` taking long in my code sample; you should see the majority of the time take up by `ToLookup`, which is where the actual database query will be evaluated.  Yes, the best solution to your problem would be to store the date as an actual date, rather than as a string.  See if it would be possible to make a view of that table that used the database to parse that string; if you could do that, and therefore expose the date column as a real date to your query it would be a significant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
var products = GetProducts(date);
var periodFaultyProducts = (from p in products.AsParallel()
                            where p.Faulty == true
                            select p).AsEnumerable();
```

Comment: Used AsParallel() to execute query in parallel. Makes a little bit faster.

Comment: `where p.Faulty == true` - really?! ... why not `where p.Faulty`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair Whatever! Explain the reason if you find the code faulty or in efficient. Don't piss off other people.

Comment: @AzharKhorasany Parallelizing is unlikely to be helpful here.  The only thing you have parallelized is filtering based on an already computed boolean value.  The overhead of threading here will more than likely slow the code down *more*.  It might, but unlikely would, be helpful to parallelize the date processing, but here you're doing it twice (once for each query) when you really don't need to.  Not duplicating that would likely speed up your code by quite a bit more.

Comment: @Servy thanks. I didn't know that. Please tell Andreas to do the same too!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the number of database requests. `ToList`, `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Any`, `Take` and `Count` forces your query to run at a database. As Servy pointed out, `AsEnumerable` converts your query from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`. If you have to find subsets you can use `Where`.